# Apk does not install on Oreo

Tags: java, android, installation, apk, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to install a signed apk (which I built with Android Studio) on a Android 8 device. The apk does not install and in the logcat of Android Studio I get the following error:

```
E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1035777424.tmp: No such file or directory
```

The app was never installed on the device so I cannot clear the app data. I cleaned the project and also cleared the cache in Android Studio. Other than that I'm using the v1 and v2 signature when creating the apk.

When installing (through Android Studio) the apk in debug mode it works but not when installing the signed release apk.

How can I fix this error so that the apk successfully installs on Android 8? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change the sdk target to api "27" in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, trying to install an APK through Firebase App Distribution.

The culprit was that I had published on App Distribution the APK that is generated by Android Studio when I ask the IDE to run the app on a device or an emulator. Apparently, such an APK is unsuitable for publishing. To correctly generate an APK that can be published on App Distribution, I had to use the `Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s)` menu item from Android Studio.